# Decompress PDF file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am making a program that can analyze graphs from PDF files. I pretty much have it working the way I want, and I'm trying to automate the script with AWS Lambda.

On my local machine using `mutool` does the job, but this doesn't seem to work on AWS.

```
command = "mutool clean -d #{input_path} #{output_path}"
system command
```

When I run that in my lambda function the `output_path` file just remains empty. How can I decompress the PDF file without using mutool/system commands?

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work " is not a technical diagnostic. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: **WARNING**: Use `system` carefully, always try and specify the shell arguments separately to avoid shell interpolation issues. `system("mutool","clean","-d", input_path, output_path)` in this case. Otherwise you **must** use [`shellescape`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape). Filenames may contain paths and other characters that could wreck your command, or worse, provide a vector for arbitrary code execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gem install pdf-reader`

```
require 'pdf-reader'
reader = PDF::Reader.new(input_path)
content = reader.pages.first.raw_content
File.write(output_path, content)
```